# Represent division as a sum of integers

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to figure out the name of the algorithm representing division operation as an array of integers you can summarize. Each element of this array must be as close to the actual rational result of the division as possible. For example:

`5/2 = [3,2]` (each element close to 2.5)

`100/3 = [34,33,33]` (each element close to 33.333(3))

`3/1 = [3]`  (each element close to 3)

It seems like a very basic manipulation. The question is just out of sheer interest: is there a common name for such operation? Maybe it's already included in every math lib and I missed this fact?

Here's how I do it currently:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Distribute(int a, int b){
    var div = a / b;
    var rem = a % b;            
    return Enumerable.Repeat(div + 1, rem).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(div, b - rem));
}
```

Comment: Why is 33 repeated twice?

Comment: @mjwills because 100 = 34 + 33 + 33

Comment: @mjwills everything is working. The only questions: is there a common name for this operation and is it a part of any standard libs?

Comment: `It seems like a very basic manipulation.` It does yes - which is how you managed to implement it in 3 lines of code. Which is likely why it is not part of any standard libs (well, that I know of).

Comment: `is there a common name for this operation` It seems a little similar to `flexible division` (but not quite the same).

Comment: With 12/5, would you prefer [2,2,2,3,3], [3,2,3,2,2] or [2,3,2,3,2]?

Comment: "It seems like a very basic manipulation" - when you don't handle edge cases like `10/0`, `10/-2`, `10/11`

Comment: @greybeard I'm ok with ordered output

Comment: @ASh yeah, that's why I asking about libs, I already had to add some logic to support negative numbers :)

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for are the `Math.Floor()` and `Math.Ceiling()` functions. They can take a decimal number and return the highest (`Math.Ceiling()`) number and lowest (`Math.Floor()`) number closest to the decimal number given to those functions.